# Wpf dynamic design with Grid and data binding

Tags: wpf

I am creating dynamic UI using from code.I am adding grid to the Page using for loop,in multiple rows and 4 columns,so it takes time to load UI on Page.I want to load each child Grid lazily, I don't know how to do it, please help.
here is XAML file

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0 0 0 0">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" Width="Auto">
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and this is pseudo code from .cs file

```
for (int column = 0; column < dsMacDtls.Tables[0].Rows.Count; column++)
{
    grid = new Grid();
    grid.Width = 108;
    grid.Height = 108;

    if (column % 4 == 0)
    {
        mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());                    
    }
    else
    {
        mainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    }

    box = new CheckBox();               
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();               
    tb.Text = "abcd";
    box.Content = tb;
    grid.Children.Add(box);

    ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
    image = new Image();
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("abcd.png"));
    grid.Background = myBrush;
    Grid.SetColumn(grid, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(grid, i);
    Border br = new Border();
    br.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
    br.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
    Grid.SetColumn(br, 0);
    Grid.SetRow(br, rowNumberofMachine);
    br.Width = 108;
    br.Height = 108;
    grid.Children.Add(br);
    mainGrid.Children.Add(grid);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try Sheldon_Xiao DataPager solution? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f72b38f1-38d6-4894-ab86-9a2e5ab5cdac/ You can download it from [here](http://cid-51b2fdd068799d15.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Samples%5E_2010/20100929%5E_DataPagerForWPF.zip)

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by to "load each child Grid lazily" - because you can obviously add/remove children whenever you want not just in something like Page_Load event.

Comment: I try to use an UniformGrid with 4 columns bind to an observablecollection, so whenever you add items to the collection, your grid will update accordingly.

Comment: Consider using an [ItemsControl](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) to render your items using a template instead of creating them in the code-behind at runtime. Also, I have some [attached properties on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-grids-rowcolumn-count-properties/) to bind the Grid's RowCount and ColumnCount that you may find useful.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your attention,I have resolved this issue by other way.

Comment: We can also use scrollview event i.e. find when scroll reached the page height then only update UI, by doing so you can prevent loading entire Grid at once